# Up and Down arrows in the Keyboard is non functional with ListboxItem selection

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

We are using a Listbox with ItemTemplate to have both Image and Textblock displayed in a single row.

We are unable to navigate using UP and DOWN arrows for the first time however the same can be used while using PageDown and PageUp events.

Actually there are 2 listboxes which are placed one beside each other when we are trying to click on the Second Listbox and then trying with Up and Down arrows it is working fine.

The issue is very strange that this is happening only for the first time when we load the screen. After clicking on the second list box and then coming back to the First listbox the Up and Down arrows are working fine.

```
<Style x:Key="_ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <!--<EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseEnter" />-->
                <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="IDC_AVAILABLE_STATIONS_KeyDown" />

                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Border Name="_Border"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="#3d94db"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                                </Trigger>

                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

---

```
<ListBox x:Name="IDC_AVAILABLE_STATIONS" Width="172" Height="98" Margin="2,6,0,0" 
                     MouseDoubleClick="IDC_AVAILABLE_STATIONS_MouseDoubleClick" 
                     ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=_ListBoxItemStyle}" 

                     VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Width="17" Height="17" Margin="0,0,0,2" Source="{Binding NetworkSetupImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                                    <Image.Style>
                                        <Style>
                                            <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{Binding NetworkSetupImage}" />
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="{Binding NetworkSetupImage}" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Image.Style>
                                </Image>
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="DisplayedStationName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="19,1,0,1" 
                                    Text="{Binding DisplayedStationName}" ToolTip="{Binding Stationtooltip}" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=IDC_AVAILABLE_STATIONS}" >
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: it seems to be a focus problem

Comment: Actually i have tried adding focus to both listbox and going further also tried to find the ListboxItem and then set focus to it. Unfortunately both of them are not working. However both PageUp and PageDown keys are working fine. The issue is very strange that it happens only with Up and Down arrows

Answer (score 0):

Just set focus to your listbox when page is loaded.

Comment: Actually i have tried adding focus to both listbox and going further also tried to find the ListboxItem and then set focus to it. Unfortunately both of them are not working. However both PageUp and PageDown keys are working fine. The issue is very strange that it happens only with Up and Down arrows

Comment: Maybe you have sample project where this issue reprodusable?